# How do I start the Flask app included with Chanjo Report?

Tags: python, flask

I installed the [Chanjo Report](https://github.com/robinandeer/chanjo-report) project with `pip` in an Anaconda env.  The README shows a screenshot of a web frontend.  There is a Flask app in the code, but no apparent way to run it.  How do I start the app?

*Update*

```
(pytools)chanjo-report ➤ python manage.py                                                                                            
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 7, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "~/chanjo_report/server/app.py", line 18, in create_app
    configure_extensions(app)
  File "~/chanjo_report/server/app.py", line 34, in configure_extensions
    api.init_app(app)
  File "~/anaconda/envs/pytools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/chanjo/store/api.py", line 48, in init_app
    uri = app.config["{}URI".format(key_base)]
KeyError: 'CHANJO_URI'

(pytools)chanjo-report ➤ python manage.py runserver                                                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 7, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "~/chanjo_report/server/app.py", line 18, in create_app
    configure_extensions(app)
  File "~/chanjo_report/server/app.py", line 34, in configure_extensions
    api.init_app(app)
  File "~/anaconda/envs/pytools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/chanjo/store/api.py", line 48, in init_app
    uri = app.config["{}URI".format(key_base)]
KeyError: 'CHANJO_URI'
```

Answer (score 0):

The project includes a `manage.py` file that uses Flask-Script to run commands for working with the Flask app.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

This file is not included as an entrypoint for the installed version, so you need to download the project and run it from there.  You can still install the project with `pip install -e .` after downloading it.